# Was flavor display changed in Android Studio 1.1? Or this is a bug in 1.1?

Tags: android-studio, android-productflavors

I updated Android Studio to 1.1 Beta4 and the Project tree view changed. The app is using flavors and before I was able to choose a specific flavor via `Build Variants` and Android Studio would load files belonging to that flavor. Files belonging to other flavors would be hidden.

Right now, when I choose any flavor, I get a toast message `Unit test support is an experimental feature. To use it your project needs to use Android Gradle plugin version 1.10 (or newer)`. Since I do not plan to use any testing in this project, I thought I could disregard this message. Or I was wrong?

Anyway, this is how `Build Variants` look now (`Test Artifact` is disabled)

[image]

However, the Project view is changed as well and now I can see all my flavors under the `/src` directory.

[image]

As you can see, I can see all my flavors directories including the general `main` one.

Q: Is this a new way of displaying flavors in Android Studio 1.1 or this is happening because I did not enable Test Experimental feature?

Q: Or this is a bug and has nothing with either of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug inside Android Studio. It occurred while I was upgrading the versions and somehow it lost idea how to display flavors.

When I exported the code and imported it into a new project using Android Studio 1.1.0, the display was the same as before this bug - flavors are changed via `Build Variants` and only one flavor was displayed.

I guess this is a very rare case that may not happen to anyone else in the future. In case anyone come across to it, just do as I did.